# How to handle not having internet connection when sending a data to server?

Tags: typescript

In the given typescript function the parameter "status" is the data I need to send to the server and it will be a string "yes" or "no". if initially the isNetworkAvailable is false we call the same function again after 3 sec. Let say the status was "yes" and later changed to "no" while isNetWorkAvailable was still false, when the isNetwork is true "no" is pushed twice to server and not "yes" followed by "no". How can I fix this? any suggestions?

```
public async sendData(status) {
    try {
        //isNetworkAvailable is a boolean.
        if (isNetworkAvailable) {
            //getParams is a random func that returs appropriate parameters.
            let response = await $.ajax(getParams(status));
            let res = JSON.parse(response)
        } else {
            throw new Error(`No Internet Connection ${status}`);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.sendData(status);
        }, 3000);

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how what you're describing is possible with the example code you've shown.  If the `status` parameter is a string like `"yes"`, it will stay `"yes"` unless somewhere the line `status = "no"` appears.  ?  Strings don't have mutable state.  Could you demonstrate this behavior for us via some web IDE project?  That is, provide a [mre], ideally one which could be dropped into a standalone IDE like [the TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/Wk5bjN).

Comment: @jcalz What if status parameter is an object and not a string?

Comment: That would be a significant change to the question.  Objects are generally mutable so that would make the situation at least possible. I strongly suggest you [edit] this question to include a [mre] that actually has the behavior you're describing when pasted into someone's IDE.